# Interrupt latency in Linux

Tags: linux, performance, time, kernel

I am trying to understand if interrupt latency in linux is dependent on kernel tick (timer).

Interrupt latency is the time that elapses from when an interrupt is generated to when the source (code) of the interrupt is handled.

I have followed the explanation in 
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/dd/interrupts.html
Which relate the mechanism to "real-time clock" tick.

Is it therefore correct to say that interrupt latency is dependent on timer tick (CONFIG_HZ), i.e. higher tick value will result in smaller interrupt latency ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interrupt latency is a measure of the time it takes to handle a single interrupt from a device. It is made up of multiple components, primarily:

- hardware latency - time taken for an interrupt signal to propagate from the interrupt source through the interrupt controller and down the CPU's pipeline
- interrupt handling overhead - saving the currently executing state, determining the source of the interrupt and calling the appropriate handler
- additional delays caused by interrupts being masked or disabled by the operating system or higher priority interrupts running (either preventing the interrupt handler from running or interrupting it while it is running)

The last one of these in particular can be very variable, so measures of interrupt latency will usually include minimum, typical and maximum values.

The primary components of interrupt latency given above are not influenced by how frequently the interrupt handler runs, however there may be some effects:

- The more recently an interrupt handler ran, the more likely it is that the code and data needed by the handler will still be in the CPU's caches.
- A frequently executing interrupt handler which delays other interrupt handlers would affect the typical latency seen by those other handlers

The specific example of the real-time clock used in the LDD chapter cited may be relevant:

- On older Linux kernel versions, the hander for the periodic interrupt run with interrupts disabled, preventing the handler from itself being interrupted, while most other interrupt handlers ran with interrupts enabled
- On systems which assign the priority of an interrupt based on which input to the interrupt controller it is attached to, the fact that the real time clock interrupt is hardwired may influence its priority

However, as I read it, the LDD chapter the question refers to is simply using the "real-time clock" tick as an example of an interrupt source. So in general the CONFIG_HZ value doesn't affect interrupt latency, although if you were to measure it there would probably be some (probably small) effect.